# How to see the contents of a file I deleted, but that a process is still writing to

Tags: linux, io-redirection, nohup, deleted-files

I started a very long running job (expected to take 6 days to finish), and want to see its output, so I did:

```
$ nohup ./thejob.sh > out.txt
```

When I need to see the job progress I `tail - f` the file.

but the `out.txt` file was growing too much and I deleted the file and created it again.

```
$ rm out.txt
$ touch out.txt
```

After this, no output is sending to the file. I think the job lost the bind to the file. I can see the job is running by using `top` but I can't see its progress anymore.

Is there any way to see it again?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The old file isn't yet gone, and you could access it if you know the PID of the process writing to it.  You can go to `/proc/<pid>/fd` and look at `1` which is it's `stdout`

This also means, though, that you haven't reclaimed any space from trying to remove the file.

Also, once the process exits, the file will be removed.

Comment: Any chance to `undelete` it?

Comment: @MagnoC If the process is still running, `cat /proc/the-pid/fd/1 > recovered-file` should give you a new copy. If it is linked to the same inode (I don't know for sure that that's the case) you could use `ln` instead